# iPhone: programmatically press a button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to press a button in iPhone SDK programmatically without the user touching it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could synthesize a touch on the button's coordinates, and set the appropriate event [here's how](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can just do:

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: how do you tell it where to send the actions to?

Comment: You can do it in Interface builder, right click your button and drag the "Touch up inside" to the object that will handle it.

Comment: You're sending it to the object inside of button variable.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want the user to see the button as pressed? Set the `highlighted` property to true and it will look like being pressed.

Now, if you just want to simulate the consequence of a button being pressed, just call the selector you assigned to the "Touch Up Inside" or "Touch Down Inside" events.

Comment: What selector is being called for camera's "capture" button?

Comment: Ilya, you can't programmatically press the "capture" button; it's a violation of Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. The user must press the button.

Comment: Ok, but guys that created the app "Big Camera Button" did it somehow - you can press anywhere on the screen to capture a photo. How can I achieve something similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

Overlay a second larger button that is transparent and assign the same selector it that you have on the other button.